# Firebase dynamic links on customdomain rewrite in hosting but how

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-dynamic-links

I've setup a custom domain to use for firebase Dynamic Links. Hosting has been setup in Firebase Console and I tried to use dynamic links without the customdomain, but just a xxx.page.link.
Now I want to return to use the custom domain, but from the console I'm told that:

> A configuration already exists for this site. Add the snippet below to your firebase.json file and redeploy your changes. Be sure the rewrite rule is the first match for your dynamic link.

I'm not exactly sure how to handle this. Should I use the CLI and init a project to make this change or can I somehow do this from the portal itself.

If I need to use the CLI, how do I then access the existing project and make the change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you're already using Firebase Hosting outside of just for Dynamic Links. In that case you'll need to configure it through the CLI.

The configuration for Firebase Hosting must be made through deploying the `firebase.json` file through the Firebase CLI. There's no way to configure this directly in the Firebase console.

You can create an empty directory, run `firebase init` in there, and configure it to your existing project. Once that is done, you can create and deploy the minimal `firebase.json` file required as shown in the documentation on [setting up your custom domain](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/custom-domains#manual).

Comment: Thank you Puf :) This is also what I ended up doing. I guess I was a little confused as I as you mentioned only did the hosting setup for custom domains. I read somewhere that the firebase.json would be overwritten when I did the init and deployed. And I wanted to get the "existing deployed" firebase.json first.....This is a bit different from my background in Azure so I just have to learn :)

Comment: Got worked Frank and finally my firebase.json looks like.
````{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
   "appAssociation": "AUTO",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",        
 "dynamicLinks": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
````